# Laravel 7.x: Darryldecode shopping cart - 'session key required' alert interferes every page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am developing an e-commerce application using darryldecode shopping cart(https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart). I've used the cart session to store every user's cart details.

The problem is, I cannot view the homepage without a registered user id, which I want to see without any authentications. The darrylcode component interferes and issuing an error 'session key is required'.

In my requirement, the user must register/login when the user adds something to the cart, so the system can store the details of the user's cart. Until then, the user can freely browse my website. (Obviously, the user cannot see the cart page.)

But, I cannot do that now as I get 'session key is required' in each and every page of the system when I browse without a registered user.

Answer (score 0):

You are using session attribute meanwhile you aren't logged in. Try login in and the  error will go out or you can use something like this if you don't want to authenticate users

```
  \Cart::session('_token')->add(array(
       'id' => $product->id,
       'name' => $product->name,
       'price' => $product->price,
       'quantity' => 1,
       'attributes' => array([
           'description'=>$request->description
       ]),
       'associatedModel' => $product
   ));
   return redirect('cart');
} 


public  function index() {
      $items  = \Cart::session('_token')->getContent();
      return view('cart.index',['items'=>$items]);
}
```

In your view:

```
 @foreach($items as $row)
    {{$row->name}}
 @endforeach
```